# Given 3 random points, what is the probability of these two situations involving a perpendicular bisector and distances?

Tags: probability, geometry, computational-geometry, computational-mathematics, uniform-distribution

Suppose we're given 3 random points $p_0=(x_0,y_0),p_1=(x_1,y_1),p_2=(x_2,y_2)$ from a two-dimensional [continuous uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) $\{U(a,b)\}^2$, for some $(a\in\mathbb{R})\lt (b\in\mathbb{R})$, and it is known that $y_0\lt y_1\lt y_2$.

Also, let $B(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the function which graphs the [perpendicular bisector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerpendicularBisector.html) of $p_0$ and $p_1$, such that $(x,B(x))$ intercepts the perpendicular bisector.

Finally, let $p_b=(x_2,B(x_2))$, let $d_1=dist(p_1,p_b)$, and let $d_2=dist(p_2,p_b)$, where $dist(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{R^2,R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the Euclidean distance between the points $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

1. Assuming $x_2\lt x_1$, what is the probability that $d_2\lt d_1$?
2. Assuming $x_2\gt x_1$, what is the probability that $d_2\gt d_1$?

> As a side note, in case anyone can point me to a source which may have information related to what I'm looking for, these questions are part of my attempting to do some analysis and optimization of [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm), which used to generate [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), given a set of points.

Comment: Got something for you: the region in which $d_2 > d_1$ is the area contained outside the lobes of a right hyperbola with asymptotes that pass through the midpoint of $p_1p_2$ and bisect the angle that $p_1p_2$ make with vertical lines.

Comment: @DanUznanski This implies that the region in which $d_2\lt d_1$ is the area contained **inside** the lobes of the same hyperbola. And since it is given that $y_0\lt y_1\lt y_2$, $p_2$ therefore cannot be in the bottom lobe.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's find the perpendicular bisector of the line $p_0p_1$.

We'll call the midpoint of $p_0p_1$ $M$, and its slope $s$.  Also, $s'$ will be the slope of the bisector, $s' = -1/s$.

$$y = s'(x - M_x) + M_y = -\frac{x - M_x}{s} + M_y$$

Now, let's find the location of a $p_2$ that happens to be exactly the same distance from $p_b$ as $p_1$ is (it'll also be the same distance as $p_0$, since $p_b$ is on the bisector).

$$y_2 = y_b - \sqrt{(y_b - y_1)^2+(x_b-x_1)^2}$$

But $y_b$ is on the line, so we can find its location based on $x_b$, and actually $x_b = x_2$, so

$$y_2 = s'(x_2-M_x)+M_y - \sqrt{(s'(x_2-M_x)+M_y - y_1)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2}$$

Everything below this has $d_2 > d_1$.

From here you'll have to integrate to find the probabilities you need.  I'm not entirely sure if that is nicely integrable though.

Comment: Also, this is complicated by the fact that $p_2$ must be inside $[a,b]^2$, yet the function for $y_2$ can possibly extend beyond $[a,b]^2$, as seen here: http://imgur.com/u3qsUvt